# is there asynchronous issue in redis

Tags: redis

If redis is a single thread server, why the result is not 100000? I think it's not redis's issue, but i want to know the reason. Thanks.

```
        RedisConnection.Default.Database.StringSet("mykey1", 0);
        Parallel.For(0, 50000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, (i) =>
        {
            var number = RedisConnection.Default.Database.StringGet("mykey1");
            int result = int.Parse(number);
            RedisConnection.Default.Database.StringSet("mykey1", result + 1);

        });
        Console.WriteLine("Result" + RedisConnection.Default.Database.StringGet("mykey1"));
```

Comment: Your operation is not [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)). It's not redis' fault. It is your code that isn't thread-safe. That means: 2 Threads can read the same value. Then, of course, they will write the same value. To get your desired behavior, you would have to make sure that one cycle of read and write is only allowed to be executed by one thread at a time.

Comment: In this specific case, that would render the use of Parallel pretty useless.

Comment: Thank you. 2 Threads can read the same value!

Comment: You can also avoid this by using "[INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr)" - which increments atomically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MULTI/EXEC to avoid this problem. It will make sure that two command will not be split by other command. It will be a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Because you make two separate calls to Redis, without the use of a transactional block (MULTI/EXEC) your `StringGet` and `StringSet` operations are not atomic.   Execution of the threads can interleave Get and Set operations.

Think about one possible execution sequence:

1. Thread1 Reads myKey1=40
2. Thread2 Reads myKey1=40
3. Thread2 Writes myKey with 41
4. Thread2 Reads myKey1 = 41
5. Thread2 Writes myKey with 42
6. Thread1 Writes myKey1 with 41

The proper way to write this code is to to replace the separate call to `StringGet` and `StringSet` with a call to `StringIncrement`:

```
    RedisConnection.Default.Database.StringSet("mykey1", 0);
    Parallel.For(0, 50000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, (i) =>
    {
        RedisConnection.Default.Database. StringIncrement("mykey1");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Result" + RedisConnection.Default.Database.StringGet("mykey1"));
```